# C++ new & delete and string & functions

Tags: c++, string, char, new-operator, delete-operator

Okay the [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965927/c-new-delete-and-functions) question was answered clearly, but i found out another problem.

What if I do:

```
char *test(int ran){ 
    char *ret = new char[ran]; 
    // process... 
    return ret; 
}
```

And then run it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){ 
   string str = test(rand()%10000000+10000000); 
   // process... 

   // no need to delete str anymore? string destructor does it for me here?
}
```

So after converting the char* to string, I don't have to worry about the deleting anymore?

**Edit:** As answered, I have to `delete[]` each `new[]` call, but on my case its not possible since the pointer got lost, so the question is: how do I convert char to string properly?

Comment: Re: Edit... Either don't lose the pointer (as per my answer below) or (better still) don't `new` the pointer, just use `std::string` to hold the string. Why do you want to do the memory allocation yourself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you are not *converting* the `char*` to a `[std::]string`, but *copying* the `char*` to a `[std::]string`.

As a rule of thumb, for every `new` there should be a `delete`.

In this case, you'll need to store a copy of the pointer and `delete` it when you're done:

```
char* temp = test(rand()%10000000+10000000);
string str = temp;
delete[] temp;
```

Comment: So how do i properly convert char to string?

Comment: I guess when you were told to convert `char*` to `std::string`, what was meant that you should **use** `std::string` rather than `char*`, not to *convert* programatically.

Comment: Could there be any simplier way to do this ? like some kind of function or something, so it would take just one line of code?

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to avoid using `char*` when you are storing a `string`. You *could* employ Smart Pointers, but that's a whole new can of worms that I am not prepared to open right now.

Comment: Yes, you can do something like `return string( ran, 'a' )`.  Take a look at string constructors http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be under the impresison that passing a `char*` into std::string transfers ownership of the allocated memory. In fact it just makes a copy.

The easiest way to solve this is to just use a std::string throughout the entire function and return it directly.

```
std::string test(int ran){ 
    std::string ret;
    ret.resize(ran - 1);  // If accessing by individual character, or not if using the entire string at once.
    // process... (omit adding the null terminator)
    return ret; 
}
```

Comment: +1 for skipping the intermediate step of creating a char *.  That said, your example code is missing a name...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, yes you do.

If you are using linux/os x, look into something like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) which can help you with memory issues

You can change your test function so that it returns a `string` instead of `char *`, this way you can `delete [] ret` in the test function.

OR you could just use a string in test as well and not have to worry about new/delete.

Comment: So i have to use: delete[] str; ?

Comment: No, str is it's own object. In this case, you have lost the pointer to the  new char[] you allocated and hence will have a memory leak since you cannot delete it.

Answer (score 2):

You **must** call `delete` for every `new` otherwise you will leak memory.  In the case you have shown you are throwing away the pointer, if you must leave the function as returning a `char*` then you will need to use two lines to create the `std::string` so you can retain a copy of the `char*` to `delete`.

A better solution would be to rewrite your `test()` function to return a `std::string` directly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++){ 
   int length = rand()%10000000+10000000;
   char* tmp = test(length); 
   string str(tmp);
   delete[length] tmp;
}
```

This deletes the allocated char-array properly.

By the way, you should always zero-terminate a string if you create it this way (i.e. inside the function `test`), otherwise some functions can easily get "confused" and treat data behind your string as part of it, which in the best case crashes your application, and in the worst case creating a silent buffer overflow leading to undefined behaviour at a later point, which is the ultimate debugging nightmare... ;)